# Accessing Outlook emails with C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to detect when I have a email come into my outlook from a certain person. I have never tried to access outlook in C# and need help getting started please.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more than this.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on how to do this online further more if you have never done something before and you know what it is you are wanting to do..then why not simply google it..? come on not you have got to at least try something or make an effort on your own..

Comment: how do you think that we all learned what you see on the internet is not re-invention of the wheel it's taking working code and editing it to fit your use case. but since your're being rude with your comments I doubt you will ever get any help here..`GOOD LUCK`

Comment: Method Man, My apologies I was having a ruff day and took your comment the wrong way. I did find the info that I was looking for that got me going all is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Outlook interop can be found here : [Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161224.aspx)

**To get started check**  :

[Outlook mail filtering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/bb612664.aspx)

[Get Address of Sender](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184647.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. For your help